# The north pole is deformed on AuthaGraph world map

Tags: coordinate-system, cartography

On the [AuthaGraph world map](https://www.miraikan.jst.go.jp/en/sp/tsunagari/authagraph.html) the world is mapped on a tetrahedron, so the map near the poles fits more the real sizes of the continents.

But isn't the north pole extremely deformed when projected on the peak of the tetrahedon?

[image: AuthaGraph world map]

It just doesn't look right, If you compare this:

[image: AuthaGraph - Europe centered and North Pole]
with:

[image]

Comment: Talk to Authagraph or Hajime Harukawa as they have patents on the projection. That is, they would probably want payment for use.

Answer (score 3):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authagraph_projection) the Authagraph is "an approximately equal-area world map projection" meaning *sizes* of regions are nearly true to scale. It also appears, to me, to keep *shapes* of regions, including both polar regions, reasonably true to form. Yes, the arctic circle gets squashed but note that *all* map projections introduce distortions of some kind. And distortion increases with distance away from the points or lines of contact (where the globe and the map coincide).

Comment: Please note that for projections like this the concept of "points or lines of contact" makes no sense.  This projection contains some heavy shape distortion--but the areas of such distortion have been concentrated near the north pole, the middles of the oceans, and a few other places (like the middle of South America).  This can be seen by looking at the graticule: shape distortion is indicated wherever two lines that *ought* to be perpendicular are not perpendicular on the map.   The graticule looks pretty good throughout most continental land masses.

Comment: So a Map where the south pole would be deformed would be interesting for Europeans: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220889/autagraph-world-map-with-deformed-south-pole-instead

Answer (score 0):

According to people who [attempted recreating the AuthaGraph projection](https://kunimune.home.blog/2017/11/23/the-secrets-of-the-authagraph-revealed/), the map indeed have some distortion, but the trick is those distortion are limited to South Pacific, South Indian Ocean, South Atlantic, and the Siberia/North Pole area, and these area are mostly covered by ocean with little population, thus they can preserve the proportion of land on the map.