# What are the main drawbacks of the AuthaGraph projection?

Tags: coordinate-system, angles, ellipsoid, curvature

The [AuthaGraph](http://www.authagraph.com/data/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/AG_EN_04.gif) projection has recently been hyped as the "perfect projection" for a world map, since it (approximately) conserves area, shape and distances. It also tessellates, so that any point can serve as an equal center point for the map.

Apart from being a fairly recent invention (so that it did not have enough time to be widely adapted), what are the main disadvantages of this projection for everyday use?

One suggestion would be that longitude and latitude are not straight lines or ellipses. This would make it difficult to find the North direction on an arbitrary point without detailed grid lines.

To address the suggested similarity [to this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216760/the-north-pole-is-deformed-on-authagraph-world-map): the deformed North Pole is only one of the symptoms of the disadvantages my question is about. My question is broader: Does this projection conserve angles? Can it easily be used for navigation with map and compass? Does it map geodesics to simple curves? etc.

---

**Summary so far**

Advantages:

- preserves size
- preserves shape
- tessellates (center point can be arbitrarily chosen)
- allows rectangular maps with almost 16:9 ratio
- allows differently-shaped maps (triangular, parallelogram)
- recurring paths (e.g. satellite orbits) can be mapped to a straight line on the tiled map

Disadvantages:

- not strictly equal-area
- lines of constant bearing are not mapped to straight lines or ellipses
- unusual projection, unfamiliar (recent invention)
- does not conserve location accurately

[image]

Comment: I think it's a great projection.

Comment: I'd like to see the data unprojected back to lat-lon. Places with a steeper curve / discontinuity can cause problems when unprojected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The north pole is deformed on AuthaGraph world map](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216760/the-north-pole-is-deformed-on-authagraph-world-map)

Comment: You can answer most of your questions by *looking* at the map.  For instance, the angles of the graticule are severely distorted around Alaska, so the map does not preserve angles everywhere--which implies it does *not* preserve shape.  The meridians are all geodesics but obviously most are not drawn as "simple curves"--in fact, they are unusually complicated.  It's unclear what you mean by "does not conserve location accurately"--no map could possibly do that. Although it is not so clear from the graticule, most satellite orbits could not possibly map to straight lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by saying not many however, one unfamiliarity would be a major drawback, for some viewing this uncommon projection may just want to stick to what they are used to.

The [orientation](https://www.wired.com/2016/11/weird-globe-folding-map-isnt-perfect-close/) of the landmasses is stretch East to West like a smiling face.

There are some sacrifices made in distance of location and shape as mentioned [here](http://www.popsci.com/annoying-persistence-bad-maps)

It can come in different orientation depending on your choice which can create a perception they may be different versions of projections.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can simply say that, authagraph has its own drawbacks for example; if we look at the map carefully, Russia looks more than twice the size of china but actually Russia is almost 3 million kilometers smaller than twice the size of China.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).