# Authagraph world map with deformed south pole instead

Tags: coordinate-system, maps

Read this first: 
[The north pole is deformed on AuthaGraph world map](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/216760/48449)

I am interested in an authagraph map, where the tip of the tetrahedron is orientated to the south pole instead, so the deformation would be condensed there.

Did someone generated such a map?

Or if not how could i generate one?

Answer (score 2):

Remember that one of the basic ideas of the Authagraph map is that you can grab different views of the world without (heavy) interruptions or repetitions simply by moving or rotating a rectangle, as is shown here:
http://www.authagraph.com/data/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/AG_EN_04.gif

I dont’t think that this is possible when you put the south pole to the tip of the tetrahedron. Because then, North America and Eurasia will always form a "circle" (well, something like a circle anyway) around the north pole which makes it hard to cut a full world map in rectangular form.

To illustrate what I’m talking about, here's an image of another tetrahedral projection (van Leeuwen), centered to the north pole:
[image: van Leeuwen projection, north polar aspect]

Try to tesselate that, you’ll see what I mean. Even when you move the center a bit, I don’t think that you’ll ever come up with a solution that can be used as mentioned above.

Comment: That looks much better on the North pole. I found further readings here: http://progonos.com/furuti/MapProj/Dither/ProjPoly/projPoly.html

Answer (score 1):

I made a tesselation of your image.

[image: I made a tesselation of your image.]

Comment: Why did you cut off the part south of Africa? can you please post a full tesselation?

Answer (score 0):

I tesselated it again and added some areas, you could select, but it really is difficult to select a useful sector:

[image]